# Squid only loads half page

Tags: proxy, squid

I have configured Squid on a VPS on DigitalOCean.
I somehow got it to accept my requests but there is a new issue now.
Whenever I try to load page using it than it only loads half of the page, what I mean is that several parts of the HTML is truncated.

Is there a default timeout value which is causing it? How to fix this?

Also the

> request_body_max_size

directive is set to default, which is to impose no limit on the size of the response.